# Web Application and ArcGIS server are two different machines and unable to load layers using rest services

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-rest-api, proxy, arcgis-web-appbuilder

ArcGIS 10.2 server is installed in one machine which doesn't have public ip. My web application is hosted in another machine and  IIS7 is configured and it has public ip. Both the machines are in LAN connection.

When we are calling the ArcGIS rest layer service from web application within LAN connection by using public/local ip, the Layers are loaded and no issues.

But when we are trying the same from outside network by using the public ip link of web application, ArcGIS rest layer services are not loaded. Because ArcGIS service url (http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:6080/arcgis/rest/) has local ip address. However the request is coming through web application which has public ip.

Is there any possibility to set the proxy to access ArcGIS server layers, or does the ArcGIS server also require public ip access?

This is my first web application with arcgis server.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes this is possible!**

There are multiple approaches for this.

You can install Apache http server from [here](https://httpd.apache.org/)
and you have to configure modjk module in this using [modJk configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html)
(You will define worker and properties here and you can add your ArcGIS server IP here)
Now you just have to call your public IP with arcgis and modjk module of Apache HTTP server will redirect the request to correct URL.

Sample modjk configuration is

> #### Define 1 real worker named ajp13
>
> worker.list=tomcatNode,gisServer

here in your case its public ip

> #### ajp connector for tomcat
>
> worker.tomcatNode.type=ajp13 
>   worker.tomcatNode.host=192.168.1.2
>   worker.tomcatNode.port=8009
>   worker.tomcatNode.lbfactor=1
>   worker.tomcatNode.cachesize=10
>   worker.tomcatNode.cache_timeout=600
>   worker.tomcatNode.socket_keepalive=1
>   worker.tomcatNode.socket_timeout=300

here in your case this ip will be your arcgis server ip (local) but make sure its static and you have to enable AJP port on arcgis server

> #### ajp connector for gis server
>
> worker.gisServer.type=ajp13 
>   worker.gisServer.host=192.168.1.1
>   worker.gisServer.port=6009
>   worker.gisServer.lbfactor=1
>   worker.gisServer.cachesize=10
>   worker.gisServer.cache_timeout=600
>   worker.gisServer.socket_keepalive=1
>   worker.gisServer.socket_timeout=1

Another way is to implement proxy page for your application. in which you will explicitly redirect the request. what you can do is you can get the request based on public IP and based on pattern "arcgis/rest/services" you can redirect it on your arcgis server IP.